# Trying to understand a c++ Plugin tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins

I'm working on my first plug in system, I have a software in C++ and I want to create a plugin system to allow users to develop their own plugins to enhance it.

To do that I'm using this tutorial:
http://www.andynicholas.com/?p=27
His complete code is available at the end of the tutorial, but I can't compile it.

I'm working on Visual Studio 2017. Here are my problems:

1) I have issues with this section: http://www.andynicholas.com/?p=27&page=5
I don't know what HINSTANCE really is (do I need any library or something?), and I have this error for the HINSTANCE line:

> error C3646: unknown override specifier

2) On the same line, I got :

> Error C4430 Missing Type Specifier. it will be used by default

3) The guy in the tutorial is using LoadLibrary(), but I can't find from where this comes from. Any idea?

If anyone can help me, I'm new to this.
Also, if you have a great tutorial on how to create a plugin system in c++, I'll be happy to read it.
Please ask if you need more details.

(Sorry for my English, and the VS errors are translated too...).

Thanks!

Comment: "unknown override" suggests that you need to enable c++11 on your compiler.

Comment: HINSTANCE and LoadLibrary are Windows API things.  Have you (directly or indirectly) included windows.h?

Comment: I though it was enabled by default on VS, it isn't? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: It's probably obvious, but, I don't know how the author is using windows api, what should I do? Thanks !

Comment: You have to include windows.h. But if he gives you the source code, that should be in there.  Did you create the project in Visual C++ or did he provide it?

Comment: He provided it, but my version of VS wasn't compatible, so VS warned me, that's probably why it's not working on my computer.

Comment: Finally everything was related to the windows api, thank you for the advice :)